# perforce progress bar

Tags: perforce

I am currently working with Perforce 4, to get the licensed version of udk. When I choose to get the latest revision, it seems to be doing something, but I can't see how long it will take or when it will end.

It occasionally shows up a progress bar but I have no idea what makes it come up, so my question is : How do I bring up this progress bar and if possible why is it freezing on me and it always freezes part way through.

Comment: What do you mean "perforce 4"? Do you mean the P4V client? Peforce version numbers have been something like xxxx.y for a long time - where the xxxx is the year and y is a major release for that year.

Comment: yes p4v client sorry i thought that meant they meant the same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The progress bar is, ahem, not entirely accurate.  That's being worked on for the next release though; should have good news on that front later this year.

Comment: ya it's really annoying is there anyway of checking my progress then accurately i have no idea when it's finished